# how to add my custom jar in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am able to create an object for a class in a jar file, which is another module.

I created a new java project with a main class, added the jar to the lib folder and I am able to create the object for that jar's class(com.canonical.client), while running the main class as a java application.

Now, I have converted this java project to maven. While I try to clean and install, I am unable to build successfully. The error given is " package com.canonical.client does not exist".

After Jespers's suggestion I am able to build the project. I am getting the following exception, while calling method which creates client object. In that jar, it looks for some other jars.

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at com.mmf.controllers.PickEquifaxController.handleRequestInternal(com.mmf.controllers.PickEquifaxController:33)
```

My manifest file's first 2 lines in that jar are as follows, its refering 118 jars actually,

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0

    Class-Path: . canonicalclient_lib/activemq-camel-5.8.0.jar canonicalclient_lib/activemq-core-5.6.0.jar 
    canonicalclient_lib/activemq-pool-5.6.0.jar canonicalclient_lib/activemq-protobuf-1.1.jar
```

What I need to do to get a solution in this. pls advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [install your JAR](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) in your local Maven repository with a command like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id>
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

where you'll have to fill in your own group id, artifact id, version and packaging - the packaging will most likely be `jar` - for example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myjarfile.jar -DgroupId=com.canonical
    -DartifactId=client -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

After doing this, you can use it like any other Maven dependency, by specifying the dependency using the group id, artifact id and version in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.canonical</groupId>
    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, Its created the jar in local repo. I can build the project without this error.... Now I am getting the error as my update to this question.

Comment: The `ClassNotFoundException` means you're missing a jar file, it looks like you're missing a dependency on `logback-core`.

Comment: I need to do all the jars as did for previous one? its 118 jars already in that jar's inner folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom jar by this way in POM.xml

`<dependency>
     <groupId>com.canonicalclient</groupId>
     <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
     <version></version>
     <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/xxx.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>`